# How do I fix a broken microwave door hook latch?

Tags: repair, appliances

I accidentally snapped off one of the hook latches on my microwave door - the door will shut, since the other latch is still there, but the safety mechanism of the oven prevents it from operating (since the second latch is not engaged).

Does anyone have suggestions on how to fix this without taking apart the microwave door (which I find intimidating)?

Comment: Nope, I just bought a new one.  Too hard getting (correct) replacement part and then installing it.  If part broke off inside main unit, really hard..

Comment: Sadly, this is a problem that is almost impossible to solve economically. We had a microwave with a broken handle. While I'm capable (and willing to do so) of making a new handle from scratch, in order to attach it, I would have had to take the door apart. It seems that they make that fairly difficult to do, since it could be a problem if someone damages the seals on the door. In the end, we bought a new microwave. Very sad.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to disassemble the door or replace it, then don't fix it. The dual-hook latch system is designed to ensure that the door is completely closed. Both hooks have matching sensors and both must be actuated for the oven to run. If you don't fix the door, then the only other option is defeating the sensors, which defeats a critical safety feature.

Comment: **Do not try to defeat the sensors!** Microwave radiation is risky. It is made safe by careful design of the doors and seals. If you cannot repair the latch by properly disassembling the door and replacing with standard latches, either bring it in for service or replace it.

Comment: I am in the middle (waiting on a part) of fixing a microwave oven. Very clear in the technical info. that if anything is done regarding the door, door latches, etc. then you MUST do a microwave leak test after the repair. Most ordinary DIYers (including me) do NOT have the test equipment to do that properly and the safety risk is BIG - don't cut corners on that.

Answer (score 1):

I popped the inner seal on the door (facing inward) the latch had a spring that was detached because thplastic hook for it broke.  I bent a wire and drilled a small hole in the latch piece and reattached the spring. If I didn’t have to figure it out, it would take 15 minutes. It took me an hour.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; would you be able to add a picture? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.